# sl4j and logback - Is it possible to programmatically set the logging level for package?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I'm able to programmatically set the logging level on the application with the following code, but is it also possible to do this *on a package level*, say com.somepackage.* where I want the level to be only ERROR rather than DEBUG or INFO on said package?

```
// Sets the logging level to INFO
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

But I can't seem to find a way to set it on a package level...

Comment: If you are casting it to logback's class, what is the purpose of using slf4j ?

Comment: I'm only casting in this case because I don't believe this is possible within sl4j, only within callback.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should set the package name as logger-name

```
// Sets the package level to INFO
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("com.somepackage");
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

You should be able to get the package name more elegant, but this is basically it.
This follows the tree like hierarchy for the Logger Context:
[Logger Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to set the root logger level, but then that isn't package specific. This package specific method behaved as if the log level was unchanged. I still didn't get the finer log messages.

Comment: Take it back. It did work for me. My xml configuration set the log level on `com.x.y` and my programmatic code based on the above answer set the log level on `com.x`. So the `.y` settings overrode my programmatic configuration.

Comment: You can also get the SLF4J logger for the package and cast it to Logback logger. Less code.
`((Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.somepackage")).setLevel(DEBUG)`

Comment: It is throwing cast exception error. java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by using logback..

```
Logger LOG = (Logger) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
LOG.setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Doesn't this just set the level for the root logger?

Comment: Didn't work for me. `ROOT_LOGGER_NAME is not a member of object ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger`

Comment: It should be `org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME` as @BrendanLong mentioned however this will only set the root logger level

Comment: how does this work? `org.slf4j.Logger` doesn't have a `setLevel` method

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't want to change the logback-classic to a compile-time dependency, here is some code that uses reflection to set this level assuming that logback is used as the slf4j runtime-binding. Here *AbcClass* is the class whose logger level you want to change to *TRACE*:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SomeClass {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass .class);
    public static void beforeEachTest() throws Exception {
        final Logger loggerInterface = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbcClass.class);
        String loggerLevelNew = "TRACE";
        if (!loggerInterface.isTraceEnabled()) {
            try {
                Class<?> levelLogBackClass = Class.forName("ch.qos.logback.classic.Level");
                Method toLevelMethod = levelLogBackClass.getDeclaredMethod("toLevel", String.class);
                Object traceLvel = toLevelMethod.invoke(null, loggerLevelNew);
                Method loggerSetLevelMethod= loggerInterface.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setLevel", levelLogBackClass);
                loggerSetLevelMethod.invoke(loggerInterface, traceLvel);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Problem setting logger level to:{}, msg: {}", loggerLevelNew, e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something similar can be done for log4j and JDK logging to make this (kind-of) library agnostic

Comment: Confirmed working. logback-classic 1.2.3. slf4j-api 1.7.25.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the SLF4J logger for the package and cast it to Logback logger. Less code that @dimitri-dewaele's.

```
((Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.somepackage")).setLevel(DEBUG)
```

@nandu-prajapati's approach is similar, except that it sets the root logger level, not the one desired.

Comment: it giving class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger exception.

Comment: @AnkitGupta Open a new question with your build file (Gradle/Maven).